# Update throws NullReferenceException on entity with multiple FK references to a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have a table `Transactions` with 4 Foreign Key references to an `Employee` table - all nullable INT fields. I create a record in `Transactions` with 3 of the Employee fields populated.  If I then update the remaining null Employee field I get the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
```

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022985/nullreferenceexception-in-ef-5-6-1-1-with-two-navigation-properties-to-the-same) which helped me identify the cause, but I still don't understand WHY it happens - Can anyone explain the reason it occurs?

My workaround is to make sure all Employee FK fields are populated on creation of the `Transactions`.

EDIT - this is not a duplicate-  it has NOTHING to do with a simple check for null.

Comment: how do you update the Employee? is your Transaction in the context at this time? when is the exception thrown (I.E. at which line of code)

Comment: I simply get the Transaction from the database, update some properties and call SaveChanges() - nothing unusual at all.  If i comment out the line that updates the EmployeeId then it works fine.

Comment: I suspect it is because EF tries to validate Navigation properties. is your Employee entry filled and is a corresponding Empoyee entry already in the database?

Comment: Yes, the Id relates to a valid Employee record.  I'm convinced that it's not a data integrity issue, but that it's related to the 4 Employee foreign key constraints.  This is code I didn't write and personally I wouldn't have written it like that, but I'd still like to know the answer.